# Unable to fetch data from Form using FormData

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, backend, form-data

I am creating an 'edit profile' page for a dashboard the technologies that I use for the same are Next.js, Node.js & MongoDB.

Note: skip to the backend part if you just wanted to know the issue.

### Frontend

**Firstly**,let me explain the `Frontend part`.

- I am using [useRef()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) inorder to reference data(*name,bio*) in the inputfields. *which are working nicely*.
- Everything is fine the issue is in the `handlesbumit()` event_handler.

  - I am using `FormData` to send my form data to the backend API
  - *If you're thinking why I'm not using a usual body object to send data the reason is that I have to add the profile picture updation later for which I have to send files , which as far I know we can't do that with an Object and yeah just to inform you it works fine if I would have used that Object part but can't use it with profilepicture updation.*
  - The value that I have consoled out for the references are all good, and the rest of the handler is just as it is written can't find anything odd in that.

```
    import { useUser } from '../../../lib/hooks';
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { ImBook, ImListNumbered } from 'react-icons/im';
import { AiFillGithub, AiOutlineTwitter, AiFillFacebook, AiFillInstagram, AiFillLinkedin } from 'react-icons/ai'
import { FaFacebook, FaStackOverflow } from 'react-icons/fa';

const ProfileSection = () => {
    const [user, { mutate }] = useUser();
    const [isUpdating, setIsUpdating] = useState(false);
    const nameRef = useRef();
    const profilePictureRef = useRef();
    const bioRef = useRef();
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState({ message: '', isError: false });

    useEffect(() => {
        nameRef.current.value = user.name;
        bioRef.current.value = user.Bio;
    }, [user]);


    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (isUpdating) return;
        setIsUpdating(true);

        console.log(nameRef.current.value); //Testing
        console.log(bioRef.current.value);  //Testing

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('name', nameRef.current.value);
        formData.append('Bio', bioRef.current.value);
        console.log(formData.get('name'));
        const res = await fetch('/api/user', {
            method: 'PATCH',
            body: formData,
        });
        if (res.status === 200) {
            const userData = await res.json();
            mutate({
                user: {
                    ...user,
                    ...userData.user,
                },
            });
            setMsg({ message: 'Profile updated' });
        } else {
            setMsg({ message: await res.text(), isError: true });
        }
    };


    return (
        <>
            <Head>
                <title>Settings</title>
            </Head>
            <main>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s12 m12">
                        <div className="card-panel br-10">
                            {msg.message ? <p style={{ color: msg.isError ? 'red' : '#0070f3', textAlign: 'center' }}>{msg.message}</p> : null}
                            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                <div className="row">
                                    <div className="col s12 m6 l6">
                                        <label htmlFor="name">
                                            Name
                                         <input
                                                required
                                                id="name"
                                                name="name"
                                                type="text"
                                                ref={nameRef}
                                            />
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col s12 m6 l6">
                                        <label htmlFor="bio">
                                            Bio
                                            <textarea
                                                id="bio"
                                                name="bio"
                                                type="text"
                                                ref={bioRef}
                                            />
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div className="center-align">
                                    <button disabled={isUpdating} className="btn" type="submit" >Save</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </>
    );
};

const SettingPage = () => {
    const [user] = useUser();

    if (!user) {
        return (
            <>
                <p>Please sign in</p>
            </>
        );
    }
    return (
        <>
            <ProfileSection />
        </>
    );
};

export default SettingPage;

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    import { useUser } from '../../../lib/hooks';
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
    import Head from 'next/head';
    import { ImBook, ImListNumbered } from 'react-icons/im';
    import { AiFillGithub, AiOutlineTwitter, AiFillFacebook, AiFillInstagram, AiFillLinkedin } from 'react-icons/ai'
    import { FaFacebook, FaStackOverflow } from 'react-icons/fa';

    const ProfileSection = () => {
        const [user, { mutate }] = useUser();
        const [isUpdating, setIsUpdating] = useState(false);
        const nameRef = useRef();
        const profilePictureRef = useRef();
        const bioRef = useRef();
        const [msg, setMsg] = useState({ message: '', isError: false });

        useEffect(() => {
            nameRef.current.value = user.name;
            bioRef.current.value = user.Bio;
        }, [user]);


        const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            if (isUpdating) return;
            setIsUpdating(true);

            console.log(nameRef.current.value);
            console.log(bioRef.current.value);

            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('name', nameRef.current.value);
            formData.append('Bio', bioRef.current.value);
            console.log(formData.get('name'));
            const res = await fetch('/api/user', {
                method: 'PATCH',
                body: formData,
            });
            if (res.status === 200) {
                const userData = await res.json();
                mutate({
                    user: {
                        ...user,
                        ...userData.user,
                    },
                });
                setMsg({ message: 'Profile updated' });
            } else {
                setMsg({ message: await res.text(), isError: true });
            }
        };


        return (
            <>
                <Head>
                    <title>Settings</title>
                </Head>
                <main>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col s12 m12">
                            <div className="card-panel br-10">
                                {msg.message ? <p style={{ color: msg.isError ? 'red' : '#0070f3', textAlign: 'center' }}>{msg.message}</p> : null}
                                <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <div className="col s12 m6 l6">
                                            <label htmlFor="name">
                                                Name
                                             <input
                                                    required
                                                    id="name"
                                                    name="name"
                                                    type="text"
                                                    ref={nameRef}
                                                />
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col s12 m6 l6">
                                            <label htmlFor="bio">
                                                Bio
                                                <textarea
                                                    id="bio"
                                                    name="bio"
                                                    type="text"
                                                    ref={bioRef}
                                                />
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div className="center-align">
                                        <button disabled={isUpdating} className="btn" type="submit" >Save</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </>
        );
    };

    const SettingPage = () => {
        const [user] = useUser();

        if (!user) {
            return (
                <>
                    <p>Please sign in</p>
                </>
            );
        }
        return (
            <>
                <ProfileSection />
            </>
        );
    };

    export default SettingPage;
```

### Backend

**Now**, the `backend API` for the same `handlesubmit()` event_handler i.e. `'api/user'`

- **Please ignore** the `handler`, it's just a predefined *middleware* `npm next-connect` which itself checks what type of request is coming if its 'PATCH' it will run `handler.patch`.
- **The Issue** is the value of `name` & `Bio` is **undefined**,which means its not getting values from req.body;
- And to check I also consoled out **req.body** which give out this [image]
- The data is correct but `req.body` is not a Object its a `String` now and I get it, its because I'm using formdata so how to get the values of `name` & `Bio` from this **req.body** ?

```
    import nextConnect from 'next-connect';
import middleware from '../../../middlewares/middleware';
import { extractUser } from '../../../lib/api-helpers';

const handler = nextConnect();
handler.use(middleware);
handler.get(async (req, res) => res.json({ user: extractUser(req) }));

handler.patch(async (req, res) => {
    if (!req.user) {
        req.status(401).end();
        return;
    }

    const { name, Bio } = req.body;

    await req.db.collection('users').updateOne(
        { _id: req.user._id },
        {
            $set: {
                name:name,
                Bio: Bio,
            },
        },
    );
    res.json({ user: { name, Bio } });
});

export default handler;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a this issue.
I was resolve it by use 2 form, a form use to get user's info as email, password and the other for  send user's picture.
Maybe has best practice for this case.